# (python/django) selenium phantomjs - executing a click event on a link ("a") element

Tags: python, django, selenium, phantomjs

I tried to simulate a click event on a link element in a selenium-based test using the phantomjs webdriver, with no success so far...

the code I'm using is:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import PhantomJS
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

class IndexTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_index_click(self):
        webdriver = PhantomJS()
        webdriver.get(self.live_server_url)
        self.assertTrue(webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#header_nav #referral a[href]'))

        previous_url = webdriver.current_url
        webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#header_nav #referral a[href]').click()
        WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.current_url != previous_url)

    def test_index_get(self):
        webdriver = PhantomJS()
        webdriver.get(self.live_server_url)
        self.assertTrue(webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#header_nav #referral a[href]'))

        previous_url = webdriver.current_url
        webdriver.get(webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#header_nav #referral a[href]').get_attribute('href'))
        WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.current_url != previous_url)
```

The output of the above is:

```
E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_index_click (functional_tests.tests.IndexTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[path cut]browse_page_as_anonymous_user.py", line 20, in test_index_click
    WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.current_url != previous_url)
  File "[path cut]lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 75, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message:

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 29.775s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

so, you can see that I did two tests just to make sure that the link is not broken - and yes, the second test, when I manually retrieve the value of the "href" attribute and make phantomjs just retrieve that uri, goes through correctly... I tried adding a longer timeout (up until 300 seconds just in case) but it doesn't make any difference...

when I add a try/except block to catch the exception and trigger a save of a screenshot there, the screenshot still shows the original page (it shows the correct target page in the second test, obviously)... but interestingly, when I modify the failing test this way:

```
    def test_index_click(self):
        webdriver = PhantomJS()
        webdriver.get(self.live_server_url)
        self.assertTrue(webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#header_nav #referral a[href]'))

        previous_url = webdriver.current_url
        webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#header_nav #referral a[href]').click()
        webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#header_nav #referral a[href]').click()
        WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.current_url != previous_url)
```

to ensure I can "click" on the link another time, the element is not there anymore and it raises:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"(...)
```

of course, I tried some other approaches but this one seems to be the most simple case and I'm at a loss why it fails to work...

for reference, I'm using python 2.7.3, phantomjs 2.0.0 and selenium 2.45.0

Thank you for any clues as to what I might be doing wrong...

**update:** for clarity, I'm not concerned too much with that "ElementNotVisibleException" - that's just an interesting follow up that I cited because that might be a hint for someone more versed in the topic but the real issue is still the fact that **executing a click() on a link element does essentialy nothing**... and that is the thing I'm trying to solve by posing the question to the larger audience here...

Comment: Have you tried saving the screenshot right before the `WebDriverWait` line, and seeing if the link is visible?

Comment: @styts I'll make sure to check that too... but I don't think that's the issue - as the "ElementNotVisibleException" pops up only after I issue .click() a _second_ time... so, as you can see above, it is not an issue in the original test scenario...